# How to configure Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit desktop for php development

Tags: 14.04, apache2.4

I have installed the Apache 2.4.7, php, mysql and phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14.04. But how do I configure my Apache Root Directory (/var/www/html/) using **symbolic link** so that it serves up my dynamic pages?

Comment: And why is a symbolic link needed?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use htaccess file to generate symbolic links. By default it doesn't work with default settings so you need to edit httpd.conf. As far as I remember it was some settings about FollowSymLinks that needs to be altered.

Answer (score -1):

It's a good question.  And I think I know the answer - which is to download the XAMPP package from AppacheFriends.org (here: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).  In addition to PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin, the package includes OpenSSL, Configuration (or quides for completing FTP access, database backup-restor, subdomains, ... well, here's what they say:

From https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20141119.html

> The following guides are available for Windows and Linux in the current versions:
>
> - Backup and Restore MySQL Databases
> - Configure FTP Access
> - Configure Virtual Hosts
> - Configure Wildcard-Based Subdomains>
> - Deploy an Application Using Git
> - Get Started Quickly with WordPress
> - Reset the MySQL Root Password
> - Send Mail with PHP
> - Troubleshoot Apache Startup Problems
>
> You can download new versions at [i can't post the link, but it's reptetive].
>
> v5.6.3
>
> - Use PHP version for XAMPP version
> - Updated PHP to 5.6.3
> - Updated MySQL to 5.6.21
> - Updated phpMyAdmin to 4.2.11
> - Update OpenSSL to 1.0.1j
> - New XAMPP welcome page (beta)
>
> v5.5.19
>
> - Use PHP version for XAMPP version
> - Updated PHP to 5.5.19
> - Updated MySQL to 5.6.21
> - Updated phpMyAdmin to 4.2.11
> - Update OpenSSL to 1.0.1j
> - New XAMPP welcome page (beta)

And here is a list of all things included (taken from the 5.5.19 package - I assume they are the same):

> Includes: Apache 2.4.10, MySQL 5.6.21, PHP 5.5.19, phpMyAdmin 4.2.11, OpenSSL 1.0.1, XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.1, Webalizer 2.23-04, Mercury Mail Transport System 4.63, FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41, Tomcat 7.0.56 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector), Strawberry Perl 7.0.56 Portable

That's a lot of stuff - all preconfigured to work together in a development environment.

Now, I have not yet installed this on Linux (I'm using Mint 17.1 - and a new convert from WinXP ... so I have plenty to learn and play with before I get into desktop development.  And I can play with a live web site anyway ... keeps me busy enough also.)  But nonetheless ... I know I will want this on the desktop, to play with soon enough.  And I have looked and looked - the XAMPP package is not available as a Ubuntu (and, thus, not as a Mint) package.  Why not!?  (A question I have posed on a Mint forum ... unanswered ... but probably the wrong place to ask it.)

XAMPP comes with all the need elements for desktop development, all preconfigured to work together.  I used it a lot under WinXP ... several versions (and after that, I put up stuff on my web site, live).  XAMPP always worked flawlessly (despite my best efforts to break things).

They also offer a significant number of add-ons - ready to download and develop (Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, MediaWiki... see: [cant post this linke either, but you can find it.]  This is new!  In my prior efforts, I installed XAMPP and then got packages like those from the source.

So ... I know that this is a tacit violation of Ubuntu protocol (to install outside the package system).  But I don't see my self trying to configure all the packages to work together.  When the time comes, I'm going outside the box and downloading XAMPP.  So, if I was you, I would

Good luck. (i'd be interested to know if you go this route, and how it works.  but I'm confident it would work perfectly.)

dgbutterworth
~ If it ain't broke - try harder!

Comment: just curious - appears I got a negative vote.  why?  i think it's a good answer.  if not ... why not?  would just like to improve.